# Visual Basic Calculations

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create a summary for my program and have no idea how to do so.
Here is my code for the program. This will calculate bank balances with deposits, checks or service charges. It also gives a $10 fee for writing bounced checks.

```
Private Sub CalculateTextBox_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalculateTextBox.Click
    'Calculate the transaction and display the new balance
    Dim AmountDecimal As Decimal

    If DepositRadioButton.Checked Or CheckRadioButton.Checked Or ChargeRadioButton.Checked Then
        Try
            AmountDecimal = Decimal.Parse(AmountTextBox.Text)

            If DepositRadioButton.Checked = True Then
                BalanceDecimal += AmountDecimal
            ElseIf CheckRadioButton.Checked = True Or ChargeRadioButton.Checked = True Then
                If (BalanceDecimal - AmountDecimal > 0) Then
                    BalanceDecimal -= AmountDecimal
                Else
                    MessageBox.Show("Insufficient Funds. Service charge of $10. ")
                    BalanceDecimal = BalanceDecimal + 10

                End If
            End If

            BalanceTextBox.Text = BalanceDecimal.ToString("C")
        Catch AmountException As FormatException
            MessageBox.Show("Please make sure that only numeric data has been entered.",
                "Invalid Entry", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
            With AmountTextBox
                .Focus()
                .SelectAll()
            End With
        Catch AnyException As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " & AnyException.Message)
        End Try
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Please select deposit, check, or service charge", "Input needed")
    End If
End Sub
```

I have created a Summary button that will display the total number of deposits, the total dollar amount of deposits, the number of checks, and the dollar amount of the checks. Do not include checks that were returned for insufficient funds, but do include the $10 charge. I have no idea how to write this summary and would appreciate any help possible! Where do I start? How can I do this?

Comment: If I could just figure out how to find the total amount of deposits... I will be able to do the rest. I just don't know how to get the total and have the amounts displayed.

Answer (score 0):

I am just speculating, but my guess is that every time the user clicks `CalculateTextBox`, you add a deposit. If this is so, you could have a variable that keeps track of the number of deposits:

```
Private deposits as Integer = 0
Private Sub CalculateTextBox_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles CalculateTextBox.Click
    'Calculate the transaction and display the new balance
    Dim AmountDecimal As Decimal

    If DepositRadioButton.Checked Or CheckRadioButton.Checked Or ChargeRadioButton.Checked Then
        ...
            If DepositRadioButton.Checked = True Then
                BalanceDecimal += AmountDecimal
                deposits += 1 'Assuming this is when the user makes a deposit.
                              'Or place this line wherever a deposit is made. 
            ElseIf CheckRadioButton.Checked = True Or ChargeRadioButton.Checked = True Then
                ...
            End If
    ...
    End If
End Sub
```